# Series Solutions Near an Ordinary Point with sin and cos

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I suppose that I just don't quite understand what is being asked here. Can somebody run me through what I am supposed to do?

Determine $\phi$''(x<sub>0</sub>), $\phi$'''(x<sub>0</sub>), $\phi$<sup>(4)</sup>(x<sub>0</sub>) for the given point x<sub>0</sub> if y=$\phi$(x) is a solution of the given initial value problem.

y''+(sinx)y'+(cosx)y=0;    y(0)=0;    y'(0)=-1